# База данных для Xamarin, WPF, веб-приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, веб-программирование, xamarin

Делаю приложение на Xamarin в будущем нужно будет его же сделать на WPF и веб версию. Т.е. будет мобильная версия, компуктерная и веб приложение.

1. Можно ли ко всем этим платформам/версиям подключить как-то одну базу данных, т.е. есть информация в базе данных и из каждого приложения получать нужную информацию к себе на платформу (мобилка, компуктер, веб-приложение)?
2. Как можно это сделать? т.е. какая архитектура, технология, приложения какие-нибудь, которые помогут осуществить это?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Обычно пишут сервер с каким то АПИ и все остальные клиенты, типа веб, настольный или мобилку, подключают к этому АПИ, который уже имеет доступ к БД

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение не требует взаимодействие с остальными клиентами\или серверами, т.е. передачи  базы данных другим  клиентам. Используйте локальную DB (пример LiteDB\Sqlite)